# How to pass data from client to server using winform signalr

Tags: c#, winforms, signalr, parameter-passing

I need to pass user Id/name after client connected (possible to get it in the onconnected function) to server (cant use connectedId), I tried different ways :

1. through IuserIdProvider.
2. through hubconnection(url,userId)
3. through querystring

Nothing worked... I am not posting my code because it is too much, all I am asking for is a link to a full example (winform please), if none of the above is good for my need or you have something better, please any other (simple) way will be great.
Thank you so much

Comment: [C# Signalr passing data from client to server winforms](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=c%23%20signalr%20passing%20data%20from%20client%20to%20server%20winforms) have you tried any of these..?

Comment: yes I googled..... I need a full example please.

Comment: I think in this case you need to show code sample of what you have tried only where it pertains to the part in your code where you are stuck..

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if this is not what I understood from your question.
You wish to pass information to the hub to do something (presumably to store into a database) AFTER you have establish a connection.
If that is so, why not invoke a method on the hub to pass the method?

Comment: I tried to pass a specific user id (not context.connectedId) and nothing worked well now I am using a querystring to pass the Id and it works fine.. but still I would like to have an IuserIdProvider example.

Comment: What kind of userId do you mean?
Do you mean like an ID assigned to user once they have signed in and your program assign an ID to that particular user?

Comment: Show us your code that call the server method to pass in your ID that you have assigned to the user. Then I can help you from there :)